# Is whereHas right way to go?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

`$provider` is optional, is it correct to use `whereHas` in this scenario even when I have already used `with()` Eager Loading?

```
public function findByStatus($status, $provider = null)
{
    $result = $this->hosts->with('logins')->where('status', $status);

    if ($provider) {
        $result->whereHas('logins', function ($query) use ($provider) {
            $query->where('provider', $provider);
        });
    }

    return $result->get();
}
```

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can you it in the way you are using. But I'd do like this.

```
$result = $this->hosts->whereHas('logins', function ($query) use ($status, $provider) {
    $query->where('status', $status);
    if ($provider) {
        $query->where('provider', $provider);
    }
    return $query;
})->get();
```

Since both the quires about `logins` you can group them in one query.

Comment: I believe the `status` part should still be applied to the outer query though.